# react-native-fbsdk error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-fbsdk

In my react-native project in **android/app/build.gradle** i have

```
...
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

...

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-android-sms-listener')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+"
    compile "com.android.support:design:26+"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar") {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
...
```

but I always get

```
<mypath> .../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

<mypath> .../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.


:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: you Should change _compileSdkVersion = 26_ and _buildToolsVersion = '26.0.1'_  in all dependencies build.gradle files @Sunrising

Comment: Should I edit files in node_modules? @SyedZainAli

Comment: Yes you will have to update file in node_modules/fb SDK

Comment: I just don't think it is the proper way, I'm sorry

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)  This Same Issue and **Solution is also Same** . You Must have look . I think Solution is Right at the Moment . If you have more better Solution you must share us .

Comment: I have added **Optimize Solution** @sunrising Now you don't have go to Node_modules  any more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. when updating to Support Library 26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to **React-Native Project** : `android/build.gradle` file and restrict `fbsdk` Version to **4.28.0**.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have another error like below:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'`.

You can try:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [rafaesc](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17147#issuecomment-351933630)

Comment: Just make sure you use the current SDK versions, which are set in app/build.gradle - ```compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"```. If it still throws an error  add ```maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }``` to the  build.gradle

Comment: Can't believe this still isn't fixed on the most recent version, thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

you go to YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle

looking for line 19:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // support react-native-v0.22-rc+
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
}
```

change compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+') to compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')

It work for me

Comment: Yeah! It worked for me. Thank you so much, you save me a lot of time

Comment: thanks. This worked for me as well.  Now, I'm getting another error message though saying `Configuration with name 'default' not found`.

Comment: This is a bad solution, it will only work until you update your dependencies and node_modules is overwritten. Also presuming your node_modules are excluded from source control nobody else will be able to run your project.