# Android Dependency Issues for react-native-fbsdk in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I followed the exact steps specified in [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)   but Android studio shows that there is an error in react-native-fbsdk's build.grandle: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt01e.png)

Beside this error, what I don't understand is that how is it possible that while my main module's compileSdkVersion is set to 23 by react-native init command, the facebook sdk uses version 26.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

I have deployed the sample project on Github [enter link description here](https://github.com/alisalimi25/fbSdkTest)

Comment: **REFERENCE** Follow link and get your Issue Solved  [react-native-fbsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a/47786292#47786292)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native-fbsdk error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a)

Answer (score 0):

I have some temporary solution for this.
try with this code.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
```