# react native fbsdk build failed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I follow [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started) to use react-native-fbsdk in my freshly created app, but whit `react-native run-android` command, I get this ..

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>       Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.

react-native version 0.55.1

Any suggestions?

Comment: Follow link for [Reference for react-native-fbsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working finally.

1) added maven in android level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

2) Changed the compileSdkVersion in the app level build.gradle file, to be the same as the compileSdkVersion in the react-native-fbsdk build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for this, here's what I did based on the answers from Vissarionas and Sachin for this question and similar ones.

### Make sure you are using the compatible version of gradle

Update **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Update **android/build.gradle** classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

### Add maven google url

Update **android/build.gradle** (both buildscript and allprojects)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

### Check that you are using at least API 26

If you are using an older react native version prior to the changes where they updated to use API 26, check these values in your **android/app/build.gradle** file:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 26
    ...
}
```